# OpenGL with C++: vtable troubles when passing class array to glTexImage2d

Tags: c++, opengl, vtable, glteximage2d

I made a class `Color` with float r, float g, float b, float alpha. It has a **base class with a virtual destructor**.

I am trying to pass an array of Color to the opengl function `glTexImage2D`, with a `GL_RGBA` organization of type float (which would be an array of {float r, float g, float b, float alpha}). This requires `Color` to contain only 4 floats (**size of 16 bytes**).

However, `sizeof(Color)` reveals that my class has a **size of 20 bytes** due to the base class of `Color` having a **vtable**, thanks to the destructor.

How can I keep my vtable and still pass my Color array to `glTexImage2D`?

Comment: In a portable, standard way? You absolutely cannot. Will a non-portable, non-standard hack do? (not that I'm aware of one, but still, you need to let the community know :)

Comment: You should not store images as an arrays of `Color`. That vtable is a huge vaste of memory in this case. And you probably don't need to have different pixel formats in a single image anyway. But if you want to pass it to `glTexImage2D`, then convert it to plain array in a separate memory buffer first.

Comment: Why are you using a virtual type anyway? What's the virtual destructor for? Does it have virtual functions? If so, *why*?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer:** No, you can't do that.

You can see all the extra parameters for `glTexImage2D()` in the [`glPixelStore()` documentation](https://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man4/html/glPixelStore.xhtml).  As you can see, there are no parameters for adding a "stride" or "padding" between pixels.  There are options for adding space at the beginning or end of rows, or between images (3D), but nothing between pixels.

**Advice:** An array of identical 4D vectors with a vtable for each is a design smell.  It is a bad design.  Your color type, in order to be compatible with C, should be a [standard layout type](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/StandardLayoutType).  Note that in particular this means that you cannot use virtual functions.

If you really need a base type with a virtual destructor, create a wrapper type.

Comment: the standard layout type is a great concept, I'll use it. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Some gl functions allow you to pass a `stride` along with the data pointer, which tells gl how many bytes it should increment the pointer to get to the next data element each time. You could pass a stride of `sizeof(Color)`, and if you can find the offset within the structure layout to get to the floats... well that would be the only way to do this that I can see. However you would definitely need to make some changes. To force adjacent layout, you would have to make the floats all held in a `float[4]`...

Regardless, `glTexImage2D` doesn't actually have stride, so this is out the window.

I think the better question is, why does your color structure have a base class or a virtual destructor? Color data is not a resource, so this is likely breaking the rule of three / rule of five / rule of zero.

You might do better to make a simple, POD type for the color, and then whatever fancy stuff you have happening in the destructor, make a second class which contains a color POD, and also has the base class etc.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The truth is I fixed the problem before asking, because the virtual destructor was indeed pointless. The base class is actually containing the first three float members. Color is really just adding a few operations, alpha and access by R(), G() and B().